# Return Json data from POST action in Core/knockout

Tags: knockout.js, asp.net-core, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am working with the [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) JavaScript library in .NET Core.  I have the following POST action that successfully receives and handles the Json data from my view.  What I cannot get to work is the return to the client:

1)  Ideally I want it to return the updated back to the view.  However there seems to be a fault with this .NET Core which means the mapping does not work.  None of the following work:

```
        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesOrderViewModel));
        return Json(salesOrderViewModel);
        return Json( new { salesOrderViewModel });
```

2) But no other return seems to have any effect either.  For example:

```
        //return NotFound();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //return View("Index");
        //return DoSomething();
    }

    private IActionResult DoSomething()
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Bird");
    }
```

Below I have pasted the View, the client side viewmodel, and the full controller action.  Can anyone give me any insight into why I cannot return anything from my controller action?

View:

```
@model Birder2.ViewModels.SalesOrderViewModel
@using Newtonsoft.Json
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sales Order Details";
}
@{
string data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model);
}
@section scripts{
<script src="~/js/knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/salesorderviewmodel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var salesOrderViewModel = new SalesOrderViewModel(@Html.Raw(data));
    ko.applyBindings(salesOrderViewModel);
</script>
}
<p data-bind="text: MessageToClient"></p>
<div>
    <div>
        <label>Customer Name:</label>
        <input data-bind="value: CustomerName" />
    </div>
       <div>
        <label>P.O. Number:</label>
        <input data-bind="value: PONumber" />
   </div>
</div>
<p><button data-bind="click: save">Save</button></p>
```

The client-side view model:

```
SalesOrderViewModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.save = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/SalesOrders/Save/",
            type: "POST",
            data: ko.toJSON(self),
            headers:
            {
                "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.salesOrderViewModel)
                    ko.mapping.fromJS(data.salesOrderViewModel, {}, self);
            },
        });
    };
};
```

The full controller action is here:

```
    //[HttpPost]
    //public JsonResult Save([FromBody]SalesOrderViewModel salesOrderViewModel)
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Save([FromBody]SalesOrderViewModel salesOrderViewModel)
    { 
        SalesOrder salesOrder = new SalesOrder();
        salesOrder.CustomerName = salesOrderViewModel.CustomerName;
        salesOrder.PONumber = salesOrderViewModel.PONumber;

        _context.SalesOrders.Add(salesOrder);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        salesOrderViewModel.MessageToClient = string.Format("{0}’s sales order has been added to the database.", salesOrder.CustomerName);

        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesOrderViewModel));
        //return Json(salesOrderViewModel);
        //return Json( new { salesOrderViewModel });

        //return NotFound();
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //return View("Index");
        //return DoSomething();
    }
```

The data are successfully bound and the database is updated).  Nothing is returned to the client.

Comment: Did you see any issues while using return type as JsonResult ?

Comment: @G_S Exactly the same behaviour, I'm afraid.

Comment: return Json(salesOrderViewModel); should work.

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that too.  I just had another go, with the return type as IActionResult and again with the JsonResult return type.  Neither works.

Comment: Even if I forget about returning Json back to the view, no return seems to work.  For example, a simple redirect back to index does not work: return View('Index');

Comment: Can you once check by commenting entire code and just do return View("Index") and check if it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165335/discussion-between-g-s-and-winthorpe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made changes to View such that we bind knockout properly and also use proper objects in success method.